# Symfony2 Service with container as a dependancy

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, containers

In Symfony2, is it possible to define a Service in the Service Container that has the Service Container as a dependance? I'm trying to build a CommandDispatcher which will pass a Command to the appropriate CommandHandler. To be able to do this, the CommandDispatcher needs the Container to query it for the appropriate CommandHandler.

Example service XML:

```
<service id="command_dispatcher" class="CommandDispatcher">
    <argument type="service" id="Container"/>
</service>
```

Comment: You can list the id and the corresponding classes of all of the available services using `app/console container:debug`. Handy if you don't know the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id for the argument should be 'service_container'

Do

```
<service id="command_dispatcher" class="CommandDispatcher">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
</service>
```